# CodeSniffer Not working with Mamp and PHP7.0.0

Tags: php, mamp, osx-elcapitan

I have searched for hours and tried several things from various posts. I am trying to install PHP codesniffer with mamp 3.5 and php7.

When I run phpcs -i, the following error is returned:

> **PHP Warning:**  include_once(): Failed opening 'PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/lib/php') in
>   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/phpcs on line 21 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/phpcs:24

**Stack trace:**

```
#0 {main}
```

thrown in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/phpcs` on line 24

Answer (score 0):

After spending a whole day i managed to make it work, by reading this [Blog Post](http://viastudio.com/configure-php-codesniffer-for-mac-os-x/)

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Server/Web/Config/php

sudo touch /Library/Server/Web/Config/php/local.ini

echo 'include_path = ".:'`pear config-get php_dir`'"' | sudo tee -a /Library/Server/Web/Config/php/local.ini
```